# Use emmet(ZenCoding) with Visual Studio for Mac (not VS Code)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-mac, emmet

I'm making an Asp.Net Core MVC application using Visual Studio for Mac.(Not VS Code)

I want to use Emmet with Razor Page(*.cshtml file.) coding, but I can not use it even by pressing the Tab key.

I feel like I was able to use it before. (It is not certain.)

Is there a setting to enable Emmet somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio for Mac does not have support for Emmet and there is no extension available that you can install.

Visual Studio for Mac has support for code snippets. If you open the Preferences dialog, select Text Editor - Code Snippets, you should find some snippets available for Razor files, and other files.

[image: Preferences - Text Editor - Code Snippets]

Code snippets are available in the completion list and you need to press tab - tab to select and then expand the snippet. However this does not match all the features that Emmet supports.